# Combine rank and sum in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

DB - Oracle. All constraints omitted.

```
create table customer (cid number(10), cname varchar(50));

create table exercise (eid number(10), ecode varchar(2), score number(2));

-- mapping table
create table customer_exercise (cid number(10), eid number(10), cnt number(10))  

Customer table

cid    cname
100    e1
200    e2
300    e3
400    e4

Exercise table

eid    ecode   score
1      c1       5
2      c2       10
3      c3       6
4      c4       3

Customer_Exercise

cid  eid count
100   1    2
200   2    5
100   2    3
300   4   10
```

SQL to retrieve total count -

```
 SELECT   c.cid
    ,e.eid
    ,COALESCE(SUM(ce.cnt), 0) AS total_cnt
FROM customer c
     CROSS JOIN exercise e
     LEFT JOIN customer_exercise ce
        ON     ce.cid = c.cid
           AND ce.eid = e.eid
WHERE c.cid IN (100, 200, 300)
      AND e.eid IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY c.cid, e.eid
ORDER by c.cid
```

Result -

```
c.cid e.eid total_cnt
100    1         2
100    2         3
200    1         0
200    2         5
300    1         0
300    2         0
```

SQL to calculate rank for each customer-

```
select cid , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum(total_score) desc) as rank from 
(
SELECT   c.cid as cid
    ,e.eid
    ,COALESCE(SUM(ce.cnt), 0) AS total_cnt
    , COALESCE(SUM(ce.cnt), 0) * e.score as total_score
FROM customer c
     CROSS JOIN exercise e
     LEFT JOIN customer_exercise ce
        ON     ce.cid = c.cid
           AND ce.eid = e.eid
WHERE     c.cid IN (100, 200, 300)
     AND e.eid IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY c.cid, e.eid, e.score 
)
GROUP BY cid
ORDER BY rank
```

Result -

```
 c.cid  rank
  200    1
  100    2
  300    3
```

Is it possible to get the resultset with one query instead of the two above? I am looking to merge the result of above two queries into one. Expected result is posted below.

Expected result -

```
c.cid   e.eid    total_cnt  rank
200       1      0           1  
200       2      5           1
100       1      2           2
100       2      3           2
300       1      0           3
300       2      0           3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The join of the three tables is used twice - once to show the counts and once more to compute the ranks. The first version is not aggregated, while the second one is (and with analytic rank calculated after aggregation). This is a perfect application of the WITH clause: do the join of three tables in a factored subquery (CTE, WITH clause) and use it twice.

```
with
     j ( cid, eid, score, cnt ) as (
       select c.cid, e.eid, e.score, ce.cnt
       from   customer c cross join exercise e
              left outer join customer_exercise ce   on c.cid = ce.cid
                                                    and e.eid = ce.eid
       where  c.cid in (100, 200, 300)
         and  e.eid in (1, 2)
     )
select j.cid, j.eid, nvl(j.cnt, 0) as total_count, r.rnk
from   j left join ( select   cid, 
                              rank() over (order by sum(cnt*score) desc nulls last) as rnk
                     from     j
                     group by cid
                   ) r
                     on j.cid = r.cid
order by rnk, eid
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `multiple CTE + SUM + DENSE_RANK()` specially for **MS SQL database** query

```
;WITH CTE_CUST AS
(
SELECT   cust.cid
        ,exe.eid
        ,exe.score
        ,SUM(ISNULL(cust_exe.cnt,0)) AS total_cnt
FROM    customer cust
        CROSS JOIN
        exercise exe
        LEFT JOIN 
        customer_exercise cust_exe
            ON cust_exe.cid = cust.cid 
                AND cust_exe.eid = exe.eid 
GROUP BY cust.cid, exe.eid,exe.score
)
, CTE_RANK AS
(
SELECT  cid, DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by (SUM(ISNULL((total_cnt * cte.score),0))) DESC) rank_score
FROM    CTE_CUST cte
GROUP BY cid
)
SELECT  cust.cid, cust.eid, cust.total_cnt as 'count', rnk.rank_score 
FROM    CTE_RANK AS rnk
        JOIN
        CTE_CUST AS cust
            ON rnk.cid = cust.cid
WHERE   cust.cid IN (100, 200, 300)
            AND cust.eid IN (1, 2)  
ORDER BY rank_score
```

Comment: `dense_rank` is not the same as `rank`, right? And giving a SQL Server answer to a question clearly marked `oracle` is about as helpful as answering "How do you say *mother* in French" with "I don't know French, but in Spanish it is *madre*". The downvote is specifically for this reason - way too often we tell people "I don't know French, but in Spanish it is......" This has to stop if we want the site to be helpful.

Comment: @mathguy : yes `dense_rank` is not same as `rank` but we can also achieve this using `dense_rank` that's what i want to say, I have given him a different approach for the same  and ya one more thing, don't be more over smart, I know he has asked for Oracle DB, but if some Sql guys are referring the same then it would be also helpful to them, If my query goes wrong then you can say other wise not

Comment: No, you can't achieve the desired result with either rank or dense_rank. As for the rest, it's on you. Keep ignoring people's tags, let's see how well you do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *SUM(...) OVER(...)* to calculate total score for each customer then rank by this value.

```
SELECT  cid, eid, SUM(cnt) AS total_cnt, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cid, total_score DESC) AS rank
FROM
    (
       select c.cid, e.eid, e.score, ce.cnt, SUM(ce.cnt * ce.score) OVER (PARTITION BY c.cid) AS total_score
       from   customer c cross join exercise e
              left outer join customer_exercise ce   on c.cid = ce.cid
                                                    and e.eid = ce.eid
       where  c.cid in (100, 200, 300)
         and  e.eid in (1, 2) 
    ) data   
GROUP BY cid, eid, total_score
ORDER BY rank, eid
```

I've created a demo [here](http://rextester.com/ZILG55379)

Comment: Don't use keywords like `rank` as column names/aliases! Use `rnk` or `rk` or similar; `rank` is the name of a function. Then: `dense_rank()` used in this context will work, if the ranks are distinct. However, if there are two `cid` tied for highest score, then the OP's query, which uses `rank`, not `dense_rank`, will produce the ranks 1, 1, 3. `dense_rank` will produce 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 (each dense_rank is repeated due to the cross join). This is not the same as the OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with two levels of analytic functions:

```
select cid, eid, score, cnt,
       dense_rank() over (order by coalece(total_score, 0) desc) as rnk
from (select c.cid, e.eid, e.score, ce.cnt,
             sum(e.score) over (partition by c.cid) as total_score
      from customer c cross join
           exercise e left outer join
           customer_exercise ce
           on c.cid = ce.cid and e.eid = ce.eid
      where  c.cid in (100, 200, 300) and e.eid in (1, 2)
     ) ce;
```

Comment: This will not work: it will assign the rank 1 twice (because there are two rows for the same `cid`, obviously both with the same total score), and then the rank assigned to the second highest total score will be 3, not 2. And the rank assigned to the third highest total score will be 5, not 3.